# PHP Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in

Tags: php

I am currently using [simple_html_dom.php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and this is the first time I think I have stumbled into this problem and I am not sure the solution (been working on it for almost two hours now.)

> ***Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in /m/viooz.ac.php on line 12***

Above is the error that is displaying on our page when we try and scrape a `a` element of the requested site view the code below.

```
$page = (isset($_GET['p'])&&$_GET['p']!=0) ? (int) $_GET['p'] : '';
$html = file_get_html('http://viooz.ac/movies/page/1/');         
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
        print '<br><br>';
        echo $url = ''.$element->href;
        $html2 = file_get_html($url);
        print '<br>';

        $link = $html2->find('.cont_display a',0);
        print $link = $link->href;
}
```

Now I know for sure that there's `<a href""></a>` tags on the site we're looking for how ever it keeps returning that error no matter what I change..

line 75 in simple_html_dom.php just says the following.

```
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
    // We DO force the tags to be terminated.
    $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);
    // For sourceforge users: uncomment the next line and comment the retreive_url_contents line 2 lines down if it is not already done.
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
    // Paperg - use our own mechanism for getting the contents as we want to control the timeout.
    //$contents = retrieve_url_contents($url);
    if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    {
    return false;
    }
    // The second parameter can force the selectors to all be lowercase.
    $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    return $dom;
}
```

> **WARNING: Don't view the content destination unless you have an ad-block you will get loads of popups.**

EDIT: Even after changing the url it returns the same issue

> **Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in /m/viooz.ac.php on line 18**

- I think I have figured something out though, when loading the page it creates a random div which triggers the popup and unless you delete that div or trigger it the other elements don't appear.. could this be what's causing our issue?

Comment: But... http://viooz.ac/movies/page/1 really does give a 404. It really is not found. So your error is expected. What's the issue?

Comment: @jszobody even when I correct the URL http://viooz.ac/movies/page/1/ which I can confirm does exist, this error remains the same when looking for the `a` element.

Comment: The page you're trying to get to is throwing a 404 -- the server can't find the page. Even though it shows a page when you browse to it, it sends a 404 error instead of a 200 OK message.

Comment: @jszobody view update please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I open your link (in Chrome incognito mode, with adblocker enabled) it really does give a 404. The page is not found, so your error is expected.

It appears you are missing a trailing slash. Add a final slash to your URL and it works.

So:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://viooz.ac/movies/page/'.$page.'/');
```

If you look at `view-source:http://viooz.ac/movies/page/1/` in Chrome, you'll see the html code that I believe you expect to see.

I confirmed that `file_get_contents('http://viooz.ac/movies/page/1/');` is successfully retrieving the HTML for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need a trailing slash on their URL, otherwise you will get the 404 page

```
$html = file_get_html('http://viooz.ac/movies/page/'.$page.'/');
```